# getView() in ArrayAdapter not getting called from AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-asynctask

In one of my android activity, I've a `ListView lvFeedsList`.
Each row element in the `listView` will contain 3 textViews - *RSSFeedName, publishDate & feedLength*

The contents of the feeds is retrived from a `HTTPRsponse`.
I'm fetching this response in an `AsyncTask`.

So, in the `doInBackground()`, I've send the `HTTPRequest` & received & parsed the response & prepared the `ArrayList` containing 3 above mentioned information.

Then inside the `doInBackground()` only, I'm creating the customized `ArrayAdapter` for forming the 3 `TextViews` in row element.
My intetions are to set this adapter on `ListView in onPostExecute()`.

But, when I run the application, the ListView does not display anything.

I tried to debug & it seems like `getView()` in the `ArrayAdapter` class is not getting called. (But I'm not sure if this is the reason).

Here is the code, sorry for the length...it seemed necessary.

**Activity Code:**

```
public class GenericFeedsActivity extends Activity{

    private ListView lvFeedsList;
    private ArrayList<FeedsClass> feedList;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
        lvFeedsList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvFeedsList);
        lvFeedsList.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        lvFeedsList.setEnabled(false);
        ...
        new AsyncResponseHandler(this).execute();
    }

    class AsyncResponseHandler extends AsyncTask {
        Context context;
        FeedListAdapter adapter;

        public AsyncResponseHandler(Context c) {
            this.context = c;
        }

        @Override
        protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) {
            ...
            /* 
             *  Sending HTTPRequest to a URL & getting list of feeds
             *  Saving this list of feeds in a ArrayList -feedList, containing elements of type FeedsClass (declared above)
             *  Below line parses the HTTPResponse XML & stores various information in feedList.
             */
            feedList = utils.parseRssResponseXML(in);   // Working fine, geeting elements
            adapter = new FeedListAdapter(
                GenericFeedsActivity.this, feedList);
            in.close();
            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Object e) {
            // Setting Arrayadapter
            lvFeedsList.setAdapter(adapter);
            lvFeedsList.setEnabled(true);
        }
    }
}
```

**Adapter Code:**

```
public class FeedListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<FeedsClass> feedList;

    public FeedListAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<FeedsClass> data) {
        super(c, R.layout.rowlayout);
        this.context = c;
        this.feedList = data;
    }

    class ViewHolder {
        TextView tvFeedName;
        TextView tvFeedPubDate;
        TextView tvFeedLength;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        ViewHolder holder = null;
            if (row == null) {

                LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater) context
                        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                row = inflator.inflate(R.layout.rowlayout, null);
                holder = new ViewHolder();

                holder.tvFeedName = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tvFeedName);
                holder.tvFeedPubDate = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tvFeedPubDate);
                holder.tvFeedLength = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tvFeedLength);

                row.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
            }
            // Getting values of feedName, publishDate & feedLength
            String feedName = feedList.get(position).getTitle();
            String feedDate = feedList.get(position).getPublishDate();
            String feedLength = feedList.get(position).getStreamLength();

            holder.tvFeedName.setText(feedName);
            holder.tvFeedPubDate.setText(feedDate);
            holder.tvFeedLength.setText(feedLength);
        }
        return row;
    }
}
```

Comment: Try call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() after setting adapter in `onPostExecute`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that you are subclassing `ArrayAdapter`. This doesn't work because `ArrayAdapter` internally thinks you do not have any elements in your data; it doesn't just magically know to look in the `lvFeedsList` variable because the data set it uses is internal.

Instead, in your constructor make sure to call this constructor instead:

**Adapter code:**

```
public FeedListAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<FeedsClass> data) {
    super(c, R.layout.rowlayout, data); // add 'data'
    this.context = c;
    this.feedList = data;
}
```

Which will make everything work correctly.

Answer (score 1):

adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

could help at the end on of AsyncResponseHandler.onPostExecute(). If not - check whether ArrayList which hold data for adapter is empty or not.